# Why is the sheaf $\mathcal{O}_X(n)$ called the "twisting sheaf" (where $X=\operatorname{Proj}(S)$ for a graded ring $S$)?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, terminology, sheaf-theory, quasicoherent-sheaves

Basically my question is why the sheaf $\mathcal{O}_X(n)$ is called the twisting sheaf, here $X=\operatorname{Proj}(S)$ and $S$ any graded ring.

Comment: Why it was downvoted?

Comment: Because the $O(1)$ of $P^1$ is morally a Möbius band, I imagine.

Comment: Ohhh this is a nice, identification, Thanks.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez: Could you explain how $\mathscr O(1)$ is a Möbius band (or provide a link)? I'm not sure if I see the connection.

Comment: @FredrikMeyer He's thinking about the real case, and actually $O(-1)$ would correspond to a Mobius band (although in this case I suppose the metric would give an isomorphism to the dual). This is an easy exercise, if you can't solve it see the beginning Milnor and Stasheff's book on characteristic classes.

Comment: I think it's called twisting sheaf because locally you just twist the ring by shifting the grading. If you know about blow-ups, see the similarities between the two constructions.